# Event timing visualization tools for real-time software design

Tags: events, real-time, visualization, scheduling, documentation-generation

I am designing a real-time system that produces outputs at a given interval, but the lengths are somewhat complicated.  I am looking for a tool that can generate a graphical representation of the timeline of events for purposes of documentation or discussion.

As an example, I may specify that A takes 10ns, B takes N*A ns, C takes 40+B ns.  Show me a graphic timeline of when things happen given this order of events A+A+A+3*(B+A+B+C)+C+C+A.
Note that the timeline is in nanoseconds, not days.

I considered a Verilog or SystemC simulation, but that is overkill and I would still like a nicer looking output than a waveform.

Is there a toolkit (GoogleAPI?, Ruby on Rails?, Excel?, LaTex?) that can do this type of thing but I don't know of anything.

Comment: Would it be too hard to write a simple OpenGL program for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need high performance, you might try [VTK](http://www.vtk.org/).

If you don't need as high performance, you could do this in [d3](http://d3js.org/), [Processing](http://processing.org/), [ProcessingJS](http://processingjs.org/), or [Protovis](http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/ex/).  They are all quite flexible and will let you do practically anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

A common tool for schedulability analysis is [TriPacific's RapidRMA](http://www.tripac.com/rapid-rma).  Coupled with Rhapsody or similar you may be able to do the type of visualization you're looking for.